# How to inplace multicolumn in specific place?

Tags: subfloats, multicolumn

I try to put it in specific place

```
    \begin{multicols}{7}
        \begin{figure*}[ht!]
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{1_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{2_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{3_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{4_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{5_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{6_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{7_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.31\textwidth]{all_signals_lunka0.png}\hfill
            \caption{lalala}
        \end{figure*}
    \end{multicols}
```

But I can't do it, it always appears at the end.

I have used this preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[warn]{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage{mathtext}               % русские буквы в фомулах
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage[noheader]{packages/sleek}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-title}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-theorems}
\usepackage{packages/sleek-listings}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{color} %
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = black,
            citecolor = black,
            filecolor=black,
            pagecolor=black,
            anchorcolor = black
            pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
            pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2 cm,bottom=2 cm,left=3 cm,right=1.2 cm}
%\usepackage[left=30mm, top=15mm, right=10mm, bottom=20mm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
%\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=1.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %междустрочный интерввл
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\frenchspacing


\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{2}
    \newcommand{\l@likechapter}[2]{{\bfseries\@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{0pt}{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\likechapter}[1]{    
    \likechapterheading{#1}    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{likechapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

% Зачем: Настраивает отступ между таблицей с содержанимем и словом СОДЕРЖАНИЕ
% Почему: Пункт 2.2.7 Требований по оформлению пояснительной записки.
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1em}


% Зачем: Определяет отступы слева для записей в таблице содержания.
% Почему: Пункт 2.2.7 Требований по оформлению пояснительной записки.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0.5em}{1.2em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.7em}{2.0em}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[parentracker=true,
  backend=biber,
  hyperref=auto,
  language=russian,
  autolang=other,
  citestyle=gost-numeric,
  defernumbers=true,
  bibstyle=gost-footnote,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{./resources/bib/references.bib}
\setlength\bibindent{-1.0900cm}
%\input{biblio/bibliopreamble}

%\FrameTBStyle{latex}

\def\tbs{\textbackslash}
```

User packages float and parskip are also included, but don't help. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Welcome to TeX.SE
- Please, always provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.
- Make MWE from your code fragments is not fun, specially, if fragment of document preamble contain packages and definitions which are not relevant to your problem.
- Help us to help you!

Sorry, it is not clear:

- How many columns has your document?
- Are defined 7 columns intended only to figure or to whole document?
- How your figure should looks. From size of figures can be concluded, that i,ages should be in three rows: 2 x three images, 1 x two.  Is this correct?

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft,
               a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2 cm,bottom=2 cm,left=3 cm,right=1.2 cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \setkeys{Gin}{trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth}

        \includegraphics{1_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
        \includegraphics{2_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
        \includegraphics{3_signal_lunka0.png}
       
    \medskip 
        \includegraphics{4_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
        \includegraphics{5_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
        \includegraphics{6_signal_lunka0.png}
        
    \medskip
        \includegraphics{7_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
        \includegraphics{all_signals_lunka0.png}

        \caption{lalala}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Off-topic: Package hyperref should be loaded (with rare exception) last in the preamble.

**Addendum:**
If you like that each sub-image has caption, you need to insert them in `subfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass[draft,
               12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin={3 cm,1.2 cm},
            vmargin={2 cm,2 cm}
            ]{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex,belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}  % because all images have zthe same dimension
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{1_signal_lunka0.png}
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{2_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{3_signal_lunka0.png}
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}

    \medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{4_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{5_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{6_signal_lunka0.png}
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil

    \medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{7_signal_lunka0.png}\hfill
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{all_signals_lunka0.png}
\caption{some text, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{lalala}
    \label{fig:lala?}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:

- In this MWE is a wee bit changed arrangement of images. They are now centered in float and distance between them is set by `\hfil`.
- Float ˙figure*` is used when in two column document it should span both columns. In such cases it is automatic positioned on the top of the next page.
- In both document example is anticipated that you try to use `multicol` for organizing images in figure and that your document has only one column.

Comment: hi. I wanted to make small pictures 1 row and 7 columns but it will be too small. so I decided to make 3x3 pictures table, but \begin{multicols}{3} didn't helped

Comment: @catauggie, As you can see, in my answer I don't use `multicolumn`.  So I ask, what is their purpose. Tell me, if showed image is what you after?

Comment: @catauggie `multicols{3}` is completely unrelated to table columns, it is for making 3-column documents, like a newspaper layout.

Comment: @Zarko, thank you for the help. It works. But can I clarify, is it possible to make a subcaption to each image, like a), b), c)...

Comment: when I make  \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{картинки/1_signal_lunka0.png} \\ a)\hfill  I got something bad((

Comment: @catauggie, (i) for subcaptions you need to insert images into subfig environments defined in `subcaption` package, (ii) regarding images: I they are unknown to us, it is unclear why are `trim`AND `clip` option is needed. In normal circumstances option `width=...` is sufficient. is needed. (iii) what you means with "something bad" is unclear too.

Comment: (ii) trim I use to cut unnecessary title of pictures))) (iii) I meant that i have subspace for a) in this case \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 22}, clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{картинки/1_signal_lunka0.png} \\ a)

Comment: @catauggie, it is better to remove undesired part of images with some other tools, but you can do on ways as you wish.